# No funciona el checbox en javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hola me echan una mano al escribir dos numeros en la cajas y seleccionar , me muestra esa palabra y llevo horas dando vuelta. alguien me da una mano.

gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido por favor lee [ask], el código en imágenes no es bien visto y menos así de pequeñas; por favor edita, agrégalo como texto y al final selecciónalo y da `ctrl + k` para darle formato

Comment: Tienes en cuenta que si el usuario selecciona todas las cajas tendrás un error, no es mejor usar input tipo `radio`?

Comment: Bueno despues miramos por ahora el probela es que funcione le chebox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema radica en tu condicional, `if(document.getElementsByName('sl').checked)` pues la tienes mal, debería de estar de esta forma:

```
if(document.getElementsByName('sl')[0].checked){
    var sumchk=nchk1+nchk2;
}
document.getElementsByName('ImprimirResultadochk')[0].value = sumchk;
```

Comment: Listo .. gracias habia omitido le array.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que ibas a hacer una función para cada operación, yo utilice una sola función para todas las operaciones, fijate que utilizo el `querySelectorAll` para traer la lista de los **inputs** tipo *checkbox*, después los recorro con un for tradicional, después extraigo su `name` o lo puedes hacer con `value` para saber que tipo de operación estoy seleccionando, después hago un `switch` para cada caso y hago la operacion y bueno num1 y num2 los convierto en numero con punto flotante `parseFloat()`, espero te sirva.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');



btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
var num1 = document.getElementsByName('num1')[0].value;

var num2 = document.getElementsByName('num2')[0].value;

var box = document.querySelectorAll('input[type = "checkbox"]');

for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
 
 if (box[i].checked) {


  var checkSeleccionado = box[i].name;

   console.log(checkSeleccionado);

  switch(checkSeleccionado){

   case 'sum':

    var suma = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);

    console.log(suma);

    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado').value = suma;

   break;

    case 'rest':

    var resta = parseFloat(num1) - parseFloat(num2);

    console.log(resta);

    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado').value = resta;

   break;
   
   case 'mult':

    var mult = parseFloat(num1) * parseFloat(num2);

    console.log(mult);

    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado').value = mult;

   break;

   case 'div':

    var div = parseFloat(num1) / parseFloat(num2);

    console.log(div);

    var resultado = document.getElementById('resultado').value = div;

   break; 
  }
 }
}




});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="num1">
  <input type="text" name="num2"><br>

  Suma:<input type="checkbox" name="sum" value="suma"><br>
  Resta:<input type="checkbox" name="rest" value="resta"><br>
  Multiplicacion:<input type="checkbox" name="mult" value="mult"><br>
  Division:<input type="checkbox" name="div" value="div"><br>

El resultado de la operacion es: <input type="text" id="resultado">&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" id="btn" name="enviar">Resultado</button>
```

Comment: Si esta interesante enseguida lo implemento así.

Comment: @JhaderCastellarT recuerda que si fue de ayuda a solucionar tu problema, dale aceptar a la respuesta (✓).